# IntelliJ / PyCharm / Webstorm keymap not working at all on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.10, intellij

I have a weird behavior of all webstorm products (IntelliJ, PyCharm, WebStorm etc.) on my Ubuntu 14.10 installation.

The IDEs work fine, everything is great, except the keymap shortcuts. None of them actually works. None at all. Also, changing the keymap settings from default to "Default for GNOME", "Eclipse", "Emacs" or whatever preset configuration does not have any effect on the functionality.

It's really strange. Anyone had this issue before?

Thanks in advance for every help.